# How long does Xendros from Ghosts of Saltmarsh need for this downtime activity?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, downtime, ghosts-of-saltmarsh

Got a question about Xendros in Ghost of Saltmarsh.

> Xendros asks for a 50 gp retainer to engage her services as an item broker each week, and the process consumes a character’s effort for a week as it involves multiple meetings to haggle over prices, specific desired features, and so on. If the characters pay the retainer, roll twice on Magic Item Table F and once each on tables A, B, C, D, and E in the Dungeon Master’s Guide to determine which magic items Xendros has on offer in any given week. (Unsold items are shipped elsewhere and regularly replaced with new options.)
>
>  If the characters want a specific item, Xendros can fulfill a request for an item from Table F or Table G with 1d4 weeks of work.

If the Player goes with the specific item. Is it 1d4 + 1 week or is it just 1d4 weeks of down time?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 9):

The wording is a little ambiguous, but here's the way my table runs Xendros:

If you want a specific item, it takes Xendros 1d4 weeks to find it. The characters can have adventures or just have several weeks of downtime until Xendros returns from sailing around the world. When Xendros returns after 1d4 weeks, the character requesting the specific item must spend a week of downtime to haggle over the specifics of pricing. So it takes a total of 1d4 + 1 week to complete the transaction, but the PCs only have to spend one week of downtime.